# To have a (bad) conscience about something - Avere la coscienza (sporca) su/di/per?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

It's the preposition that's the problem!
I've found:

> Avere la coscienza di/su qualcosa

and

> Avere la coscienza sporca per/di qualcosa

but I can't find anything definitive in either case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find those constructions?

Comment: Just searching on the net for egs in Italian with the various prepositional constructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an Italian, I'd definitely say *avere la coscienza sporca per [qualcosa]*, but it's always good to double-check and look for sources.

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+coscienza+sporca+per%2Cla+coscienza+sporca+di%2Cla+coscienza+sporca+su&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=33&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20coscienza%20sporca%20per%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20coscienza%20sporca%20di%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cla%20coscienza%20sporca%20per%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20coscienza%20sporca%20di%3B%2Cc0), from a purely “big data” point of view, seems to confirm that *avere la coscienza sporca su* is out of question, and *avere la coscienza sporca per* prevails, but seems to observe a significant presence of *avere la coscienza sporca di* too.

However, looking for examples of the latter construction one mostly finds that *di* refers to the person having the bad conscience. For instance,

> la coscienza sporca di chi dimentica

or

> si alzò con la coscienza sporca di un traditore

and so on.

On the other hand, there are also some examples where *di* introduces the thing the bad conscience is about, such as

> Riccardo sapeva bene che questo era solo un tentativo di coprire uno scottante “affaire” internazionale, nonché la coscienza sporca di un evento passato e non un fatto di interesse nazionale

and

> perché aveva la coscienza sporca di non averlo riconosciuto in clinica

The latter sounds unusual to me and, were I the editor, I'd discuss it with the author or translator, but this means that someone uses it. And I may well be wrong in criticising it: the Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana is not rich in [occurrences of “coscienza sporca”](https://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Sequenza?q=coscienza+sporca), but [one of them](https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/16?seq=79) (third column), albeit in Roman dialect, is indeed:

> Camilla, de certo, nun doveva avé fiatato, co  quela coscienza sporca  d’avé ricettato la merce, co tutti l'ori e le pietre

from no less than Carlo Emilio Gadda.

Comment: My first question and what an excellent answer. Thankyou.

Comment: @Ellen If the answer is satisfactory, you should "accept" it (there's a special checkmark-shaped button on the left of the answer). It helps the system knowing that your question has a satisfactory answer (and it gives a small additional reward to DaG - he does not need it, but it's still nice) And welcome to Italian.SE, I hope to see you around again.